# Stuck when executing sshd with absolute path

Tags: windows, ssh, command-prompt, sshd

To let you know, I am very newbie. So I managed to make a machine (windows 10) a ssh server. Everything worked smoothly. But after the PC being restarted when I try to run again the command "sshd" in the prompt I get:

```
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
```

I tried to execute the absolute path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe
```

But I simply get stuck. I am not even able to write anything in the command line.

Comment: I just upgraded to Windows 11 and see the same now. This used to work on Windows 10.